# How to integrate: $f(x) =\frac{ \cos5 x +5 \cos 3x+ 10\cos x}{\cos 6x+6\cos 4x+15 \cos 2x+10}{dx}$

Tags: integration

$$f(x) =\frac{ \cos5 x +5 \cos 3x+ 10\cos x}{\cos 6x+6 \cos
4x+15 \cos 2x+10}{dx}$$

I applied Eulear formula 
$$e^{{ \iota}x} = u$$
$$\frac{ u^5 +\frac{1}{u^5}+ 5 (u^3+ \frac{1}{u^3}) + 10(u+ \frac{1}{u}) }{u^6 + \frac{1}{u^6} +6(u^4 + \frac{1}{u^4}) +15(u^2+ \frac{1}{u^2}) +10}$$

$$\frac{ u^5 + 5 u^3+ 10u +\frac{1+5u^2+10u^4 }{u^5} }{ u^6  +6u^4  +15u^2+ 5 + \frac{1+6u^2+15u^4+5u^6}{u^6} }$$

$$\frac{ u^{10} + 5 u^8+ 10u^6 +10u^4+5u^2+1  }{ u^{12}  +6u^{10}  +15u^8+ 10u^6 +15u^4+6u^2+1 }{u}$$
But I think this is not the right way to solve this problem . Please guide me a good way do this .

Comment: Ouch  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(cos5x%2B5cos3x%2B10cosx)%2F(cos6x%2B6cos4x%2B15cosx%2B10)dx

Comment: Looking at the answer given on WA I am interested in the manual solution !

Comment: Use this http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to recognize that $f(x)$ simply equals $\frac{1}{2\cos x}$, you just have to notice that

$$ 2\cos(x)\left(\cos(5x)+5\cos(3x)+10\cos(x)\right)=\left(\cos(6x)+6\cos(4x)+15\cos(2x)+10\right)\tag{1}$$
as a consequence of
$$ 2\cos(x)\cos(nx) = \cos((n+1)x)+\cos((n-1)x).\tag{2}$$
Then
$$ \int\frac{dx}{\cos x}=\int\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2 x}\,dx = C-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right).\tag{3} $$

Answer (score 0):

The Wolfram Alpha solution is from before the question was corrected. (The $\cos{2x}$ in the denominator was formerly $\cos{x}$).

Note that the coefficients at the top are $0, 1, 5, 10, 0$ and the coefficients at the bottom are $0+1, 1+5, 5+10, 10+0$. This gives the following idea:

Substituting $\frac12(e^{nix}+e^{-nix})$ for $\cos{nx}$, we get $$\frac{ e^{5ix} +5e^{3ix}+ 10e^{ix}+10e^{-ix}+5e^{-3ix}+e^{-5ix}}{e^{6ix}+6e^{4ix}+15e^{2ix}+10+15e^{-2ix}+6e^{-4ix}+e^{-6ix}}$$ for the integrand, which equals $$\frac{1}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$$ or $$\frac12{\sec{x}}\text{.}$$

I'll leave that integration to the reader.

Comment: How you simplified the expression ?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of my answer. $\frac{ \cos5 x +5 \cos 3x+ 10\cos x}{\cos 6x+6\cos
4x+15 \cos 2x+10}$ is $\frac12\sec{x}$.

Comment: Can you explain how noting coefficients at the top are $0, 1, 5, 10, 0$ and the coefficients at the bottom are $0+1, 1+5, 5+10, 10+0$  give you this idea ?

Comment: I saw that adding pairs of adjacent coefficients at the top gave the list of coefficients at the bottom, and that the pattern was complete if I added "$0$" to the beginning and end of the top coefficients. That made it feel as if the bottom was in some sense "the top multiplied by $x+1$". After that, it was a question of giving a correct shape to the intuition.

Comment: The fact that the coefficients look a little like binomial ones ($(x+1)^5$ at the top, $(x+1)^6$ at the bottom), nearly sent me down completely the wrong path. That resemblance was entirely deceptive!

Answer (score 0):

Aakash Kumar, I think that you were near a simplest form. You can use the binomial formula so as to express $u^n + \frac{1}{u^n}$ in function of $T = u + \frac{1}{u}$ and its powers *(this change of variable is a classical technic for finding roots of symmetric polynomials)*.

Using this inside $\dfrac{ u^5 +\frac{1}{u^5}+ 5 (u^3+ \frac{1}{u^3}) + 10(u+ \frac{1}{u}) }{u^6 + \frac{1}{u^6} +6(u^4 + \frac{1}{u^4}) +15(u^2+ \frac{1}{u^2}) +10}$, you can normally prove that $f(x) dx = \dfrac{dx}{2 \cos x}$.

You can use the following SageMath code in [a SageCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org) to confirm this *"magically"*.

```
f(x) = (cos(5*x) + 5*cos(3*x) + 10*cos(x)) /(cos(6*x) + 6*cos(4*x) + 15*cos(2*x) + 10) 
f.trig_simplify()
```

Now you can apply what we call [the Bioche's rules](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gles_de_Bioche) in France. This is not the same rule as the [brioche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brioche) ones *(sorry for this so bad play on words)*.

Here the rules say to use $w = \sin x$.

$f(x) dx = \dfrac{1}{2\cos x} \times \dfrac{dw}{\cos x}$

$f(x) dx = \dfrac{dw}{2(1 - w^2)}$

$\int f(x) dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \tanh^{-1} w$

$\int f(x) dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \tanh^{-1}(\sin x)$

Be a little paranoiac. The following code gives a starting point to test some numerical valid values with the help of [SageCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org).

```
f(x) = (cos(5*x) + 5*cos(3*x) + 10*cos(x)) /(cos(6*x) + 6*cos(4*x) + 15*cos(2*x) + 10)
print numerical_integral(f, 0, 1)
formal = (arctanh(sin(1)) - arctanh(sin(0)))/2
print formal.n()
```

### HOPING THAT I HAVE NOT MADE ANY ERROR... ;-)

If this is the cas, we have here a good example of some calculations that are not direct to do with any CAS (Computer Algebra System).